# Symfony 2 unchecked checkbox missing in POST data

Tags: forms, symfony

Unchecked checkbox is not present in GET or POST data.

How to handle it?
Is there need to do it manually or there is another reason why symfony $form->getData()  does not handle it automatically?

Comment: It is an html thing.  Unchecked boxes have no value and are not sent by the browser.  On the other hand, form->getData knows this and will compensate for it.  Perhaps you could post a bit of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony by default parse your checkboxes to an array so if you have a checked one you will have it in your `form->getData()` else you will not have it, so in your controller if you don't get your checkbox in form data that's mean that the checkbox is unchecked

Comment: Answer is good, Symfony is stupid. To drop an existing form entry instead of each form field being in POST but null r empty array.

Answer (score 0):

As explained above

I had the same issue, to be honest I dont understand why there is no option value for unchecked checkboxtype like 'unchecked_value' => false

I had to manually go over submitted fields, check if field has not been submitted then I know it is missing in form submit and that means it equal to false.

this is in my class to be run before persisting...it will basically loop over properties and set its values to false

```
public function setUncheckedReplacementFields(array $data)
{
    foreach($this as $property => $value){
        if(str_contains('Replacement', $property) !== false){
            if(!in_array($property, $data)){
                $method = sprintf('set%s', ucfirst($property));
                if(method_exists(this, $method)){
                    $this->$method(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

before I am persisting form I run this

```
$object->setUncheckedReplacementFields($request->request->get($form->getName()));
```

so if field is not part of form I know it has been unchecked and I loop over object to find those checkboxes and setting them to false in my case unchecked.